# Is it good that reading config values rather than using magic numbers?

Tags: c#

I have an idea that reading values from config files instead of using hard code values, but I'm not sure it is a good practice or not.

First I created a utility class:

`public class ConfigValues
{ 
    public static int Read(string key, int defaultValue){....}
    public static string Read(string key, string defaultValue){....}
    public static bool Read(string key, bool defaultValue){....}
    ...
}`

The Read function tries to read value for the given key. If the key doesnot exist or the value has bad format, it returns the default value. And I'm going to use this class like:

`public class MyClass
{ 
    private int _age = ConfigValues.Read("Com.MyClass.Age", 0); 
    ...
}`

So that, we can make almost all variables in the application customizable.
Will it be a good practice? 
Please comment it for free.

Comment: Do you use web or windows applications?

Comment: What platform, please retag your question narrowing the question to the environment you are using

Comment: It will apply to both Windows and Web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People who think you should make things configurable:

- Some of the other answers
- http://www.ebizq.net/blogs/decision_management/2007/04/dont_softcode_use_business_rul.php
- Many good software development theories (I don't have links handy).

People who think differently:

- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/21/Enabling-change-by-hard-coding-everything-the-smart-way.aspx (And the [rest of his entries](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:ayende.com+JFHCI))
- http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Soft_Coding.aspx
- http://benbro.com/blog/on-configuration/
- http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/hardcoding-considered-harmful-or-is-it/

The answer comes down to your requirements: why are you setting this value here?

- Is it something that different users will want set differently? => config file.
- Is it just a default value to be changed later? => Hardcode it.
- Is it something which affects operational use of the program (i.e. default homepage for browser)? => Config file.
- Is it something which might have complex impacts on various parts of the program? ... Answer depends on your userbase.

Etc. It's not a simple yes-it's-good or no-it's-bad answer.

Answer (score 2):

Configuration files are always a good idea.
Think of the **`INI`** files, for example.

It would be immensely useful to introduce a version numbering scheme in your config files.
So you know what values to expect in a file and when to look for defaults when these are not around. You might have hardcoded defaults to be used when the configurations are missing from the config file.

This gives you flexibility and fallback.

Also decide if you will be updating the file from your application.
If so, you need to be sure it can manage the format of the file.
You might want to restrict the format beforehand to make life simpler.

You could have **CSV** files or "`name=value`" **INI** style files.
Keep it simple for your code and the user who will edit them.

Comment: The only caveat is that all of your classes suddenly become dependent on this config file.  That might be fine for your application, but sometimes makes it a pain to test individual classes.  In those cases, you'd want a "factory" class that readsthe configuration file and then instantiates MyClass like new MyClass(age).

Answer (score 0):

Configuration file also allow you to update the values without doing another build to change a single value.  This can be useful to have one build for all environments, with different configuration values (log levels, user names, etc.).  Also, if you cache the values and periodically update from the file, it allows you to make changes on the fly while the application is still running.  This may be overkill in some situations, but it can be very helpful in debugging certain issues.

Answer (score -1):

Do:

- Create a new C# project
- Menu->Project->[Project name] Properties
- Open Settings pane
- Create your settings (it's strongly typed)

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int setting1 = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1 = 43534;            
        Proerties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Note that **Properties** is a namespace and you can import it so you can use Settings.Default.Setting1.

[Here is a more detailed link](http://csharp-projects.blogspot.com/2008/01/windows-forms-user-settings-in-c.html).

If you use a windows forms application, you could change the Program.cs file to save all the changed settings when leaving application:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Add this line
        Application.ApplicationExit +=
                            new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    //and this method:
    static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```